# Can I have a "Live" Navigator in Photoshop CC?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, software-recommendation, cc-2014, plugin

I record my work by capturing the navigator on a second monitor at 1920x1080. This is much easier on the eye at 16x speed because the screen isn't shooting all over from zooms and panning. However, the navigator only updates when an action has finished. This means that long brush strokes add pauses to the recording.
I need a way to either modify my navigator to update during an action. Or to somehow duplicate my canvas at a different zoom level and be truly "live".
Id love to hear anyone's ideas or plugin information that might help, thanks!

Comment: do you have youtube channel?

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can. Go to **Window>Arrange>New Window for "abc"**. Now you have two windows that will  mirror each other.

You can have them side by side by going to **window> arrange > two up vertical**.

I think this is called Dual view photo editing.

Comment: I started to post this as well. Unfortunately, a new window will suffer from the same "only update after action" issue.